# How to declare a property of an anonymous class

Tags: c#

In my application I must serialize/deserialize some data. Now I use code like this:

```
public class Outer
{
  public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
  public string InnerProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How can I avoid declaring inner class? I need something like this:

```
public class OuterNew
{
public class Inner2
    {
    public string InnerProperty { get; set; }
} 
}
```

But inner class must be property (have get/set) to work with serialize/deserialize correctly.

Comment: What do you call an 'anoymous class' ?

Comment: Are you confusing *anonymous* with *nested* class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of Inner2 only defines a class, you still need a property as well:

```
public class OuterNew
{
    public class Inner2
    {
        public string InnerProperty { get; set; }
    } 

    public Inner2 Inner { get; set; }

}
```

But as you can see this only changes the full name of Inner2,
it is now called `public class <namespaces>.OuterNew.Inner2`.

So you might as well use the first snippet, and in general nested public types are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your first block is okay and should be the code to use. There is no problem with it, so I am not sure what problem you are trying to fix.

In your second code block you still need to create the property. Now you just have an inner class that sits there waiting to be used.

You can circumvent creating classes for deserialization by using `dynamic`, but really, keep using the code you are now. Your code will be less error-prone without using `dynamic`.

Comment: The main problem that I don't want to declare >100 public classes that are only used for serialisation.

Comment: Then you should see if you can simplify the datamodel and thus the number of classes used. Can you use a dictionary for example?